# How to define global macro pointing to the static class method of the same name?

Tags: compiler-errors, syntax-error, mql4, mql5

I've the following MQL4/5 code:

```
class MQL4 {
public:
  static double Ask() {
    MqlTick _tick;
    SymbolInfoTick(_Symbol, _tick);
    return _tick.ask;
    // Overriding Ask variable to become a function call.
    #define Ask MQL4::Ask()
  }

};

void start() {
  double ask = Ask; // line 14
};
```

However it fails to compile under MQL4 or MQL5 as per errors:

```
> mql /s /mql5 Test.mqh
MQL4/MQL5 Compiler build 1162 (02 Jul 2015)
Test.mqh : information: Checking 'Test.mqh'
Test.mqh(14,16) : error 320: 'Ask' - too complex, simplify the macro
Test.mqh(14,16) : error 239: '::' - syntax error
Test.mqh(14,16) : error 239: '::' - syntax error
Test.mqh(14,16) : error 239: '::' - syntax error
Test.mqh(14,16) : error 239: '::' - syntax error
Test.mqh(14,16) : error 239: '::' - syntax error
Test.mqh(14,16) : error 239: '::' - syntax error
Test.mqh(14,16) : error 239: '::' - syntax error
Test.mqh(14,16) : error 149: unexpected token
Test.mqh(14,16) : error 149: ')' - unexpected token
Test.mqh(14,16) : error 157: 'MQL4' - expression expected
Test.mqh(14,10) : warning 31: variable 'ask' not used
 : information: Result 11 error(s), 1 warning(s)
```

<sup>Same errors with the latest 1498 build.</sup>

Basically it's saying that `Ask` macro is *too complex macro*. Although it works fine when I rename **`Ask()`** method to **`GetAsk()`** and update the macro definition,
however
I'd like to understand
if there is any other solution without having to renaming it.

Is there any syntax that I can define a [macro substitution](https://docs.mql4.com/basis/preprosessor/constant) which can understand the following macro:

```
#define Ask MQL4::Ask()
```

without having to rename it while still keeping it in the static class method?

Answer (score 1):

### YES, but ..., no!
`#define` substitution works fine, but ...
 but **`Ask`** is a reserved word, which confuses the compiler.

The problem is actually with the limited capabilites of the compiler pre-processor,
not with the **`.method()`**'s "same name".

The **`#define`** directive, both non-parametric and parametric, substitution capabilities were tested to the limits of the published MQL4/5 language syntax.

---

### `Case[6]` finally proves,

the `Class.<_method_>()` **can have the same name** **`.Ask()`**, but it cannot be the same as the **`#define`**-s `<_literal_symbol_to_substitute_>`

```
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                   StackOverflow__test_DEFINE.mq4 |
//|                                       Copyright © 1987-2017 [ME] |
//|                                                       nowhere.no |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
#property strict
 // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*                                                       // [Case[1] FAILS BELOW
#define               Ask MQL4::Ask( True )              // [Case[1] // Overriding Ask variable to become a function call. */

class MQL4 { 
     public:
     static double Ask( bool FakeSyntaxSUGAR = False ) { // [Case[1] FAILS HERE TO PROCESS EXPANDED PRE-PROCESSOR #define SUBSTITUTION]
                        MqlTick _tick;
                        SymbolInfoTick( _Symbol,
                                        _tick
                                        );
                        return _tick.ask;
         }
};

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Script program start function                                    |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+

void OnStart() {

 // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*                                                       // [Case[2] FAILS
#define               Ask MQL4::Ask( True )              // [Case[2] // Overriding Ask variable to become a function call. */
  // double ask     = Ask;                               // [Case[2] FAILS TO COMPILE, ERROR on "Ask;"]


  // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // double askMQL4 = MQL4::Ask( True );                 // [Case[3] OK    TO COMPILE EXPLICIT CALL TO an explicit absolute reference to a method-name]


 // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*                                                       // [Case[4] OK */
     MQL4* aPtrToINSTANCE = new MQL4();                  // [Case[4]
  // double askINST = aPtrToINSTANCE.Ask( False );       // [Case[4] OK    TO COMPILE EXPLICIT CALL TO aPtrToINSTANCE-referred instance of Class ]

 // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*                                                       // [Case[5] FAILS
#define               Ask aPtrToINSTANCE.Ask( False )    // [Case[5] */
  // double askINST = Ask;                               // [Case[5] FAILS TO PRE-PROCESS #define HERE ]


 // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*                                                       // [Case[6] OK */
#define               Ask_with_SomeOtherDEFINE_NAME aPtrToINSTANCE.Ask( False )
     double askINST = Ask_with_SomeOtherDEFINE_NAME;     // [Case[6] OK    TO CALL THE .Ask() METHOD AS THE PRE-PROCESSOR <_SYMBOL_TO_SUBSTITE_> WAS #define-d AS NON-COLLIDING]

//    **   *   ****        ****        *****        *****
//    ***  *  **   *      **   *       **           **   *
//    ** * *  **   *      **   *       ***          **    *
//    **  **  **   *      ** * *       **           **   * 
//    **   *   ****  **    ****   **   *****  **    *****  **
//                   *         *  
}; 
// ------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

### Epilogue:

> As I have posted [**somewhere in some other MQL4-posts**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20%5Bmql4%5D), after having some extensive testing of the capabilities available from the **`#define`** directive based pre-compiler substitutions ( for version management purposes et al ), I could but draw **a conclusion to try to avoid using this feature**, as the resulting problems were far more expensive ( surprising string-handling limitations, uncertainties about the continuing language creeps, unpredictable results of syntax-sugar tricks after next Build releases etc. ) than beneficial for the purposes intended.

Comment: So in other words you're saying it's not possible without renaming the variable or method?

Comment: 'Ask is a reserved word, which confuses the compiler' this is not correct, if you change `Ask` to `Foo` across the code, the compiler will show the same errors about too _complex macro_, so it's not about a reserved word.

Comment: In which **`Case[id#]`**? Well, no one can rename the hard-coded 
"system register" **`Ask`**. Next, the weakest point is the `#define` pre-compiler substitution, that sequentially substitutes all appearences of **each**  `<_literal_symbol_to_substitute_>` after which the lexer typically gets panic. **Sorry, this is outside of the control of the MQL4/5-side code-design.**

Comment: Your first sentence saying that ('Ask is a reserved word, which confuses the compiler'). The `Ask` variable in MQL5 doesn't exist and the same happens there, so it's not about reserved word. I think the main problem is that value of macro definition has macro name in it, so every `Ask` is replaced with value of it, then the same happens after replacement over and over again until few iterations when compiler realizes that it's too complex.

Comment: Yes, this was mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: If you uncomment and re-test the different `[Case[id#]]`-s, the error messages will vary a bit, be different as per where the collision started, but typically show a divergent panic of the pre-compiler substitution combined with lexer panic on growing complexity of the intermediate representation it cannot somehow satisfactorily terminate in code-structure analysis and gaves up in a panic state after some 30 nesting levels.

Answer (score 0):

macro substitution should be declared somewhere away from the function. try to move `#define Ask MQL4::Ask()` above the class declaration or to the first line of your program

UPD. after conversation it turned out that macro should have different name.

```
#define method (Class::method()) //doesnt work, 
#define method (Class::Method()) //or (Class::method_()) is fine
```

Comment: It won't make any difference, as compiler won't see it as in the function. It's just placed after Ask method definition for convenience.

Comment: you are doing sth wrong. look: your code [link](https://gyazo.com/1060fee05e55ea39f6df134750487587) and output [link](https://gyazo.com/325f032e3b7fecbcc3465550138d95f2) - moving macro away and putting all in () is enough

Comment: The order doesn't matter, but in your code you've already renamed `Ask` to `ASK`, then it works fine. But I want point `Ask` macro into `MQL4::Ask()` explicitly. Using `ASK` with capital letters isn't the standard [predefined variable](https://docs.mql4.com/predefined/ask) in MQL4, since existing MQL4 code running under MQL5 would be using that class would use `Ask`, not `ASK`. So workaround changing the names is the one which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: indeed. if renaming function to ask() - it works. maybe it doesnt want to have macro and function name equal